# Unable to delete files to trash in a bind-mounted filesystem

Tags: mount, bind-mount, trash

I'm trying to set up shared home directory for two Linux installations and thus I'm using bind-mounts. My user is named `dbz` and his home directory is `/home/dbz`. I also have shared directory `/home/shared` where I store my shared files (this folder is also owned by user `dbz`).

I mount another directories from this shared directory into my home directory using binding:

```
mount -B /home/shared/work /home/dbz/work
```

This solution solves my needs and the only issue I have and don't know how to resolve is - when I'm trying to delete a file or directory from mounted directory I cannot delete it to trash, only permanent deletion is possible.
For example:

- deleting file `/home/shared/work/test.txt`: OK, because deleting right from the directory where the file `test.txt` resides;
- deleting file `/home/dbz/work/test.txt`: CAN'T, because... by the way, because what? do bind-mounts have some restrictions on file deletion?

Finally [an issue submitted to bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70831)

Comment: Is `/home/shared` and `/home/dbz` on the same filesystem? (i.e. `/home` is a mount point)  What you are describing is a *cross device link*; `mv` works by creating a link and removing the original. When the src and dst are in different mounts, this cannot happen. (the bind should be transparent to the process.)

Comment: @RickyBeam Yes, the `/home` is a mount point, so `/home/shared` and `/home/dbz` are on the same filesystem and even on the same mount point. All I do is bind-mount folders in `/home/shared` to folders in `/home/dbz`

Comment: Seems this is a bug in `gvfs`. I've found an old [bug description here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=698640) and seems it still not fixed.

Answer (score 9):

This is a linux kernel issue.  It's not looking at the true super-block of the source and destination filesystems:

```
17926 rename("d1/foo", "d2/foo")        = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

Looks like the issue is in `do_rename()` (`fs/namei.c`):

```
    error = -EXDEV;
    if (oldnd.mnt != newnd.mnt)
            goto exit2;
```

*sigh*

Comment: Thank you once again! I [submitted an issue on bugzilla.kernel.org:](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70831)

Comment: I see that bug report went no where. I knew it would, some kernel devs are really quite thick. It's not an EXDEV as both mount points are the same dev. (I "fixed" this decades ago in my own tree, so one could recover deleted-but-still-open files from procfs -- ln /proc/<pid>/fd/# /real/location/file)

Answer (score 8):

In order to make a trash directory you need to be able to make `.Trash_<uid>` at the mountpoint (at least on Ubuntu when deleting from nautilus, your
distro might use another directory). If that directory cannot be made because the parent is not writable by `dbz`, you will not be able to backup.

It should not be necessary to have the parent directory writeable, it suffices to create the `.Trash_<uid>` as root and then `chown` it to `dbz`.

I find it somewhat easier to test things regarding trash file creation using the `gvfs-trash` utility, which actually gives an Error if the file cannot be trashed.
Use something like:

```
touch /home/dbz/work/test.txt
strace gvfs-trash /home/dbz/work/test.txt  2>&1 | grep .Trash | grep mkdir
```

to see which directory it actually tries to make.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I created `.Trash-1000` at `/home/dbz` and at `/home/shared`, and even at `/home` (and then owned by `dbz`), but no success. Your example gives me the following  output:  
  `mkdir("/home/dbz/.local/share/Trash/info", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)`
  `mkdir("/home/dbz/.local/share/Trash/files", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)`  
And doing `gvfs-trash /home/dbz/123/1/` gives the following output:  
  `Error trashing file: Unable to trash file: Invalid cross-device link`

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a symbolic link for any of the parent directories of the Trash directory to another filesystem. I had `~/.local/share/Trash` soft linked to a directory on a different filesystem, which led to this error. Of course, it still should work, but a work-around is to keep the Trash on the same filesystem.

Also, I found that the Ubuntu `trash` from package `trash-cli` works with that symlink, whereas `gvfs-trash` which is used by gnome applications does not work.

Comment: thx on the trash-cli tip, an alternative on my answer may help :)

Answer (score 0):

On nemo you can use this:
place this file at:
~/.local/share/nemo/actions/trash.nemo_action

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Move to Tra_sh(cli)
Comment=Trash even on mount binds
Exec=xterm -title "Trashing(cli)" -e trash -v %F
Selection=any
Extensions=any
EscapeSpaces=true
```

you can remove the xterm part and keep just the command.
you can change the shortcut but I suggest just pressing the context menu key over the files and just hit 's'.
I tested it with 1 file, many  files, 1 folder and many folders selected, all worked!
I am quite sure this can work on nautilus too, I just dont remember where you should place an equivalent action.

PS.: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177100/how-to-fix-not-working-trash-on-bind-mounts-in-ubuntu-19-04-and-hide-them-in-n/1360837#1360837